# PushNotification options for c# server to iOS device

Tags: asp.net-mvc, push-notification, onesignal, azure-notificationhub, pushsharp

Is it possible to use OneSignal to create a native PushNotification to an iOS device from an asp.Net server? What's the difference between OneSignal and PushSharp? Is the difference that I would have to setup OneSignal on my mobile app instead of just allowing the app to hit endpoints on my server to register/unregister for pushNotifications(Which I was planning to use PushSharp for)

The webapp is currently being hosted on Azure, so the notification hub is an option too. But would the communication hub make me be tied down to azure?(Say I wanted to host my webapp on a different service and maybe change the server code to node)

On mobileApp startup, I'd like to send a request to the server to register the device token. It'd be best if I didn't have to config the app.

edit: I also contacted OneSignal with questions, I'll report back with any findings.

Comment: AFAIK, PushSharp is just a server-side SDK for sending notifications to APNS,FCM/GCM,WNS,etc. Both OneSignal and Azure Notification Hubs could send notifications from relevant back end to the relevant platforms. You need to follow [Azure Notification Hubs overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview) and [OneSignal overview](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs) to compare them based on your requirement (cost, scalability,telemetry,etc.) and choose the right one.

Comment: For using OneSignal on your mobile app,you'd better just leverage the related server SDK ([OneSignal-CSharp](https://github.com/mundipagg/OneSignal-CSharp-SDK)) provided by OneSignal. When using push notification service, it would help you to manage configurations for push against different platforms. While for PushSharp, you need to explicitly create related instance (e.g construct the `ApnsConfiguration` for APNS, `GcmConfiguration` for GCM,etc.) in your back end for sending notification request to OneSignal server, then the server would send notification to the related PNS (APNS,etc).

Comment: After talking to a OneSignal rep i got a lot more confused. It seems like we'd have to set up something on the mobileApp to be able to send a push notification from the server right?

Comment: Yes, your mobile app needs to communicate with the related  notification service (OneSignal,Azure Notification Hubs,etc.), details you could follow [OneSignal : iOS SDK Setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup) and [Get started with Azure Notification Hubs for iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started).